# empty graphs using panel in python

Tags: python, widget, panel, hvplot

## i get empty graphs and i dont know the reasons for this. may the data types or something else likw the code itself.

## type          string

## director      string

## country       string

## rating        string

## Create a RadioButtonGroup widget called graph

`
graph = pn.widgets.RadioButtonGroup(name='Y axis', options=['rating',], button_type='success')

## Create a new pipeline

graph_pipeline = ( idf[ (idf.country.isin(checkbox_group))] .groupby(['type'])[graph].nunique() .to_frame() .reset_index() .sort_values(by=['type']) .reset_index(drop=True))

## Create a visualization interactive using hvplot

graph_plot = graph_pipeline.hvplot( x= 'rating', y=graph, line_width=2, title="Test", width=800, height=400,     legend='top' )
graph_plot`